# How to plot station names (text) from csv file to map

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I have a plotted map with station locations (from a CSV) but I am finding it difficult to add text to the points using their station name referred to as "STATIONS" in the first column of the CSV file attached.
Below is the code compiled so far. Thanks.

'''

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as feature
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shapereader
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, 
LatitudeFormatter
import pandas as pd

countries = shapereader.natural_earth(resolution='10m',
                                      category='cultural',
                                      name='admin_0_countries')

# Find the Nigeria boundary polygon.
for country in shapereader.Reader(countries).records():
    if country.attributes['SU_A3'] == 'NGA':
        nigeria = country.geometry
        break
else:
    raise ValueError('Unable to find the NGA boundary.')

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax_map = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax_map.set_extent([-1, 19, -1, 17], ccrs.PlateCarree())

#ax_map.coastlines()
ax_map.add_feature(feature.COASTLINE, linewidth=.5)

ax_map.add_geometries([nigeria], ccrs.PlateCarree(), edgecolor='0.8',
                  facecolor='none')

grid_lines = ax_map.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
grid_lines.top_labels = False
grid_lines.right_labels = False

lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True)
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()

ax_map.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax_map.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)

df = pd.read_csv("met_ngstation.csv")

plt.scatter(df['LONG'],df['LAT'],
                    color='red', marker='.', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

#plt.savefig('coastlines_ng.pdf')
#plt.savefig('coastlines_ng.png')

plt.show()

'''
```

Link to CSV file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_0b7z7WFfrs5eKY3t7-tykRoZ70Vqjkn/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function below to mark the stations on the plot.

```
def labelLocation(x, y, val, ax):
    dt = pd.concat({'x': x, 'y': y, 'val': val}, axis=1)
    for i, point in dt.iterrows():
        ax.text(point['x'], point['y'], str(point['val']))

labelLocation(df['LONG'], df['LAT'], df['STATIONS'], plt)
```

[image]

Comment: @Rao Thank you for your quick response. After running the codes, I got this message: "posx and posy should be finite values
posx and posy should be finite values". Did you receive the same message and what does it imply?

Comment: @Dayo yes i get that as warning. there is a row with NaN values in your data. you should preprocess such unknown values before you pass to the function.                  
 `45  Koko NaN NaN Delta`